# Is it necessary to use AMF library when using flash.net.Socket class to read custom object from java?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, amf

When I try sending String, int primitive value from java side to AS, AS can read it successfully. But If I send a custom object to AS, AS can't decode it. Does it mean
flah.net.Socket must rely on AMF library like BlazeDS to decode custom object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the case. It is actually also the case for primitive ints, but AS3 is implicitly converting the int string into an int for you, if you save it in a int variable.

By the way, you do not *have* to use the Socket connection to use AMF, but you certainly *can*.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm not sure what does "you do not have to use the Socket connection to use AMF" mean? When use socket.readObject(), both server and client side definitely should use AMF library, right?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's right. But you can also use AMF over normal HTTP requests/answers. You can even save AMF as a file and load it later. AMF is not bound to socket as a protocol.